# Trouble representing terms for the momentum equation using Fipy

Tags: python-3.x, solver, pde, fipy, fluid-dynamics

How would i go about representing the dyad (tensor product) in the following equation? I can't seem to figure out what terms in Fipy I should be using in general.

[image: Cauchy]

More specifically the resulting equation:

[image: Cauchy]

I'm mostly familiar with the transient and source terms, but I am at a loss on how to represent [image: Term]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more going on there than you're interested in (multi-phase with phase transformation), but see [`liquidVapor1D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/reactiveWetting/generated/examples.reactiveWetting.liquidVapor1D.html) and [`liquidVapor2D`](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/blob/master/examples/reactiveWetting/liquidVapor2D.py) for examples of implementing the momentum equation.